# Application_OnAuthenticateRequest executes for image requests

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm using Application_OnAuthenticateRequest in Global.asax to assign a custom principal to HttpContext.Current.User and System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.
In testing, I noticed that this code executes multiple times for a single page request.  By looking at the HttpContext.Current.Request.Url I determined that this code is executing for each call to a JavaScript file, Image, and CSS file.  All of these resources are stored in a single subfolder called "Content".  So, I'm able to prevent multiple executions of my custom principal by checking to see if "Content" is part of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url like so:

```
protected void Application_OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/Content"))
        return;

    if (Context.User != null)
    {
        if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUserRepository>();

            var prospectorUser = userRepository.GetByUserName(Context.User.Identity.Name);

            if (prospectorUser == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Context.User.Identity.Name is not a recognised user.");
            }

            var principal = new ExtendedWindowsPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, prospectorUser);

            // Attach the new principal object to the current HttpContext object
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            // Make sure the Principal's are in sync
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My fix seems kludgy.  Is there a better way to trap requests for "Content" items and prevent my custom code for my principal from firing for every request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AuthenticateRequest` event occurs pretty high up in the HTTP pipeline.  If you want to bypass it in certain cases for your application, you'll probably need to write an `HttpModule` that is registered to handle a given path.

Take a look at Figure 9, 10 and 11 in the article below.  You should be able to follow it to build a custom module to handle requests to the Content path, and bypass all the regular event processing.

[Securely Implement Request Processing, Filtering, and Content Redirection with HTTP Pipelines in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188942.aspx)

Comment: My initial attempt at this approach ended up preventing the resources in the Content folder from being downloaded to client.  So, no images, CSS, scripts, etc. I created a httpModule which intercepts requests.  If the request contained "content" in uri, then I completed request and set the response code to 200, but none of the resources are being sent to client.

Comment: You probably can't just complete the request - you'll still need to pass the request off to an IHttpHandler that will send the content, or manually send the file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is the modify your web.config to make the 'Content' folder anonymously accessible:

```
<location path="Content">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I thought this too initially, but my hunch is that AuthenticateRequest is still going to fire, and hence execute his kludge.  Would love some confirmation on that though.

Comment: I commented out my check for "Content" in Application_OnAuthenticateRequest then added the <location>..</location> to my web.config and it did not make a difference.  My principal code would fire for all content related requests.